# How can we add Toolbar and FloatingAction button in all Parent and Child Activities in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hi aim very new for android and in my app i am adding "ToolBar" added Floating Action Button in my MainActivity ok that's fine see my below code

Here my main Requirement is how can we add this ToolBar and Floating Action Button in all other remaining Activities i am not understand please help me some one(of-course ToolBar is adding in all other Activities if we add it once in Parent activity then it's also applying to child activities also that's fine)

but how can we add this Floating-Action Button in all other Child Activities please help me some one

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.venkat.actionbarapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### parentActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

### ChildActivity:-

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_main);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `SecondActivity` should be called child of `MainActivity`? Anyway, you will have to define `fab` in `SecondActivity` too.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiO9der7LfLAhVFj44KHaxwAukQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8821240%2Fandroid-how-to-create-my-own-activity-and-extend-it&usg=AFQjCNFLBpCbYbogzhJtTiiHDAVGQ8k4yQ&sig2=zD5iDB82UmX-Z0QiMZ4hXg&bvm=bv.116573086,d.c2E&cad=rja

Comment: how can we do that i am very new for this technology please explain with some code @Rohit Arya

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use only one `toolbar` and `fab` in all your **views**, I would recommend using `fragments`. Declare `toolbar` and `fab` in the activity layout and framelayout will contain all fragments.

Comment: no no i want to use separate toolbars and fabs in for each views but how can we do that i am not understand please provided some code

Comment: In that case, you will have to define `toolbar` and `fab` in all your activities. OR, you can try extending one *BaseActivity* containing `toolbar` and `fab`. BTW, I would still recommend using `fragments` because you can always update you `toolbar` and `fab` for different fragments.

Comment: please provided some code then i can use ur suggestions i have just entered in this technology two days back

Comment: if u don't mind i will send my sample project file please do this in my app please help me

Comment: add your `content_main` layout file.

Comment: can i send my sample project file please see once?